# Thread local storage / Windows

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, thread-local-storage

Given native code (C/C++), could someone explain thread local storage? Is it simply a trick that allows threads to control the lifetime of their own variables, or is there some isolation/protection enforcement by either the compiler or the hardware?

Does the underling platform matter?

Further more, what is the difference between plain TLS and "Fiber-safe" TLS, with respect to the above?

Sorry, I googled, but all I could find was how to use TLS (which I already know) but not the geeky details behind the scenes.

Comment: Check out this link (not my article) for further links to full exposition on TLS: http://bryanpendleton.blogspot.com/2010/11/ken-johnsons-exposition-of-thread-local.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thread-local Storage (TLS) is managed by the OS.  Every thread object in the kernel contains a local array of TLS slots.  At runtime, the app's code can call `TlsAlloc()` for each TLS variable it needs (such as for variables declared as `__thread` or `__declspec(thread)`, depending on compiler) to reserve available indexes into the TLS array.  Each thread can then use `TlsGetValue()` and `TlsSetValue()` to read/write values that are stored in the calling thread's TLS array at those indexes.  When done using TLS, the app can call `TlsFree()` to release its reserved indexes.

For example, at app startup, the app calls `TlsAlloc()` once to reserve TLS index 0.  Inside each thread that subsequently runs, any given thread can call `TlsSetValue()` for TLS index 0, and that value will be stored locally for that specific thread, thus values stored at TLS index 0 for other threads will not be affected.

Refer to MSDN for more details:

[Thread Local Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686749.aspx)

Fibers run inside of threads.  So multiple fibers running in the same thread will share the same TLS array for that thread.  If one fiber sets a value at TLS index 0, all fibers running in that same thread are affected.  Fiber-Safe TLS is just a compiler optimization that prevents a fiber from caching any TLS information, in case that fiber jumps from one thread to another during its lifetime.

Comment: Note the pitfall of __declspec(thread): "Consequences of using variables declared __declspec(thread)" at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/11/22/10094489.aspx

Comment: Thank you. Does the OS-level enforcement imply any type of security, such as preventing other threads from seeing the local variables, through poking around in the process space? I do not have a good example of why that would be desired, but I'm just trying you understand what "is managed by the OS" means.

Comment: The TLS array is private inside the kernel thread object. "Managed by the OS" means just that. The OS allocates and manages the array, the app does not have direct access to it, only access to the contents of the array via the TLS functions. Can a thread poke through another thread's TLS data? In theory, yes, if you use undocumented APIs and direct memory access. Is it worth doing that? No. It defeats the purpose of what TLS is.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer: when a thread starts, the GS segment register points to a (mostly undocumented) OS data structure for that thread.  One of the elements of this data structure is an array of 64 PVOID elements, used by the TLS functions to store up to 64 TLS variables.

Comment: Seems like a lot of Windows structures are undocumented, even though Windows has existed since the 80s, and we are 2014 now, and still it's undocumented?!

Comment: @farmdve: it is usually preferable not to publicly document internal implementation details, because it makes it far more difficult to make any changes later on.  The relevant team(s) within MS will have their own documentation, of course, it just isn't available to the public.