# Is it possible to create thread private variables?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, thread-local-storage

Say I'm doing a multi-thread database linking dll.

The dll will be loaded into the process address space and will be called by different threads.

To operate database simultaneously with different threads, I would need each thread to have its own connecting structure to the database.

Furthermore, if each thread has numbers of tasks to perform, it would be not efficient to connect and disconnect to DB each time a task is performed.

So would it be possible to create a thread variable that will exist along the thread? Therefore, it would be possible to connect to DB while initializing of the thread and disconnect while destroying it.

The platform that I'm using is Windows server 2008, and I'm writing my code with C.

Thanks a lot~

Comment: Look up thread local variables. Win32 threads have a couple different types.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18088928/694576